# Nodejs +Nodemailer @4.6.4 + Emailtemplates @3.6.0

Tags: node.js, nodemailer, email-templates

I tried to send Mails with Nodemailer. [Nodemailer](https://community.nodemailer.com/2-0-0-beta/templating/) itself works fine. But I also need Templates, so I googled a bit about it and found [email-templates](https://github.com/niftylettuce/email-templates) . I added it to the project, installed it. All fine. I create a Template, and all is working fine in dev mode but not in production mode (on a live server) 
When I try to send a mail from my server, Nodemailer errors with following error:

```
{ Error: No recipients defined
at SMTPConnection._formatError          (node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:606:19)
at SMTPConnection._setEnvelope (node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:815:34)
at SMTPConnection.send (node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:431:14)
at sendMessage (node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-transport/index.js:226:28)
at connection.connect (node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-transport/index.js:287:21)
at SMTPConnection.once (node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:188:17)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
at SMTPConnection.emit (events.js:208:7)
at SMTPConnection._actionEHLO (node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:1128:14)
at SMTPConnection._processResponse (node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:762:20)
at SMTPConnection._onData (node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:558:14)
at Socket._socket.on.chunk (node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:510:47)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:211:7)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12) code: 'EENVELOPE', command: 'API' }
```

The error is clear. No recipients defined, meaning I "missed" the "to" parameter for Nodemailer. But I don't missed it. Nodemialer can't detect it from the Mailoptions (email) given in my function.
Ok so here is my code.

Import needed Modules

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const Email = require('email-templates');
```

Create a transporter for node

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 25,
        secure: false,
        tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    });
```

Create a new Mailtemplate with email-template

```
  const email = new Email({
        template: '../Services/Mail/emails/activation',

        message: {
            from: from,
            subject: subject,
            to: userEmail,

        },
        locals: {
            username: username,
            url: url
        },

        transport: {
            jsonTransport: true,
            to: userEmail,

        }
    });
```

Send Mail with Nodemailer

```
  transporter.sendMail(email, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(email);
            return console.log(error);
        }
        console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);

        console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
    });
```

The next problem is that, Nodemailer [tutorial](https://community.nodemailer.com/2-0-0-beta/templating/) for external Mailrendering is deprecated and I have no idea how to fix it. Does anyone know how to send E-Mails mit Nodemailer and email-templates. Sorry for the the inconvenience.

Nodemailer Version: 4.6.4
Email-templates Version: 3.6.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to use a separate Nodemailer, because email-templates has already integrated Nodemailer itself. So, for you to be able to send out the email using Nodemailer, just set transport option with a Nodemailer transport configuration object, and enable send option of email-templates. To sum up, your code should be like below:

```
const email = new Email({
    template: '../Services/Mail/emails/activation',

    message: {
        from: from,
        subject: subject,
        to: userEmail,

    },
    locals: {
        username: username,
        url: url
    },
    send: true,
    transport: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 25,
        secure: false,
        tls: {
             rejectUnauthorized: false
        }
    }
});
```

After that, call the function send of email-template (as in its document: https://email-templates.js.org/#/):

```
email.send({
    template: 'mars',
    message: {
      to: 'elon@spacex.com'
    },
    locals: {
      name: 'Elon'
    }
  })
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Tanks for your reply. Will test it ;)

Comment: Nice explanation, the docs are kinda confused about it, it wasn't very clear where the `transport` configs should be inserted and / or if the `nodemailer` was still supposed to stay at the initialization. Thanks. =]